# div tag won't wrap text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am appending a div called chat-message into a div called card-block, however I want it to wrap the text so that it does not go out of screen. I tried using the CSS property:

```js
var message = document.createElement('div');
message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
message.innerHTML = "<preBot>" + data[x].name + ": " + data[x].message + '</preBot>';
messages.appendChild(message);
messages.insertBefore(message, messages.nextSibling);
```

```css
.chat-message {
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">
        Quick ORDR
        <button id="clear" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
      </h1>
      <div id="status"></div>
      <div id="chat">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name..." style="display:none;" wrap="soft">
        <br>
        <div class="card">
          <div id="messages" class="card-block" style="overflow:auto;">

          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <textarea id="textarea" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message..."></textarea>
        <br />
        <div class="yes" style="display:none;"><button id="yes" class="btn btn-success" display="none">Correct</button> <button id="no" class="btn btn-danger">Incorrect</button> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The prebot tag is just for textcolor and justification and making sure there are page breaks. When I run the code, the text I enter behaves as normally, just keeps going to the right.

Comment: whats is messages?

Comment: Anyway if you want your text to wrap to next line, all you need is a fixed width element with { white-space: normal; }

Comment: is <preBot> being interpreted as a <pre> element? That would cause what you describe.

Comment: Without seeing a working example it's hard to be certain, but It sounds like a simple case of setting a width. If the div runs off of the screen then so too will its text content

Comment: messages is the div in which i am sending all of my created div called chat-message

Comment: That's the same as your innerHTML except the strings are using an advanced syntax of template literals of which modern browsers support. The <preBot> tags have no significance to this demo because it's non-standard, it is also invalid unless you can provide the plugin/code/framework that makes <preBot> tag more than just a <div>

Comment: Your existing CSS is one ruleset to which is replaced by a similar yet better property. You claim that my code messes up yours, do you expect my code to merrily fit with yours when I haven't seen it in it's entirety? Your justification done with `<pre>` tags is a joke. The reason why you can't wrap your text is because of the PRE tags. BTW are the `<preBot>` tags acting like real `<pre>` tags or did leave out too much of the CSS to see why you can't wrap text in a div (divs naturally wrap text so your CSS is convoluted and out of control or you are fighting the effects of a poorly chosen tag.)

Answer (score 0):

Textarea does not accept much in the way for formatting. The only control you are given for layout are line breaks. You cannot push a DIV into a text area. A DIV is a DOM element. Texboxes only accept text - not DOM elements.

use the  \n newline character to break your text into multiple lines inside a textarea.

Comment: Im sorry i misspoke, i meant to say that i and appending a div into a div called messages, also this is a chatbox type of formatting so everything is dynamic